# Which verb describes the movement of a flag or clothes on clothes line?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, vocabulary

Which verb describes the movement of a flag or clothes on clothes line?  The wind moves a flag or clothes,but what is the  proper word for this movement?

Comment: Probably _flapping_; that means rhythmic movement of a flexible two-dimensional object. This is entirely coherent with the phonosemantics of [the `FL-` assonance](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/fl.pdf). That's what flags do in a breeze when they're being flown properly, too, although if the breeze is brisk enough, they can be said to _snap_, which is [a different assonance](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/sn.pdf), though still coherent.

Comment: Depending on the strength of the wind, flags tend to flap, flutter, billow or stream. They might also ripple, or flail.

Comment: So if the wind is light,the most appropriate word would be billow?

Comment: There are many options. Which is best depends as much on what the flag is doing as on how strong the wind is. To add to the above, for light movements, waver, sway, and swell could all describe the motion of the flag. If you want to describe the *wind* as the agent, however (as in your second sentence), most of these won't work.

Comment: And of course, if there is no wind or very little, a flag can *flag*.

Comment: Most generally, _waving_.

Comment: And *wafting*, too. Said of clothes, spiderwebs, kites, curtains, flowers, etc. Aspen leaves *quake* in the wind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Wave*** would be the most general verb.

> to move freely and gently back and forth or up and down, as by the action of air currents, sea swells, etc.: *flags waving in the wind.*
>
> <sup>http://www.thefreedictionary.com/wave</sup>

Other than that, as mentioned in the comments also, there are the verbs ***flutter, fly, flap, billow, ripple, snap, flaunt*** and ***stream*** that you can use depending on the context or depending on the strength of the wind.

You can see this comparison in [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=waving%20flag%2Cfluttering%20flag%2Crippling%20flag%2Cstreaming%20flag%2Cbillowing%20flag%2Csnapping%20flag%2Cflying%20flag%2Cflapping%20flag%2C%20flaunting%20flag&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwaving%20flag%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfluttering%20flag%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crippling%20flag%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstreaming%20flag%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbillowing%20flag%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csnapping%20flag%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cflying%20flag%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cflapping%20flag%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cflaunting%20flag%3B%2Cc0) also:

[image]

Comment: I'm hard pressed to use fly, snap, flaunt, or stream with regards to the waving motion of a flag in the wind. To fly a flag means to raise it. To flaunt it means, well, to flaunt it!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to say what the wind does to the flag, rather than what the flag does in the wind, use flutters (light wind), whips (strong fast wind), ruffles (gentle irregular wind), and search synonyms for those -- just make sure they are verbs that can take a direct object (the wind does X to Y, not just the wind does X)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe "a flag flies" or "a flag flutters"...

Answer (score -1):

flowing is one of the verbs for flag

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. A proper answer in this community will demonstrate research or citations from reliable sources. Otherwise answers become mere opinion. You will do well to edit your answer, demonstrating the sources of your answer. Thanks..