# What is the best adjective to describe when a flag is flying perpendicularly like in this image?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, image-identification

[image]

It is Flag Day, and the US flag is on my brain. I can think of *erect, unfurled*, and *at attention* to describe a flag flying perpendicularly to the ground in a strong wind, but I feel like I’ve heard another word. Am I missing something?

Comment: It is _flying_.

Comment: Erect?.........

Comment: Related: [Which verb describes the movement of a flag or clothes on clothes line?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/198770/which-verb-describes-the-movement-of-a-flag-or-clothes-on-clothes-line)

Comment: It could be described as *flying* but flying also refers to the practice of sticking a flag on a flagpole regardless of the wind ([example of the latter](https://www.flaginstitute.org/wp/uk-flags/british-flag-protocol/): "What rules apply when flying flags in the UK?").

Comment: Near-horizontally

Comment: You mean parallel to the ground? Or perpendicular to the post?

Comment: There is only a description, no single word.

Answer (score 1):

***Flying***, ***horizontal*** or some combination of both.

The Lunar Flag Assembly was created to

> make [the flag] appear to fly on the airless Moon as it would float in the wind on Earth.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_Flag_Assembly)

Indirectly, the term *horizontal* is used throughout that article, such as in the following sentence.

> Pete Conrad and Alan Bean, the crew of Apollo 12, had trouble with the latch mechanism which was supposed to keep the supporting pole horizontal, so the flag they deployed drooped at an angle.

Note that supporting pole is supposed to be horizontal, and therefore hold the flag horizontal as well.

Answer (score 1):

Flags ***stand out*** in a stiff breeze.

A search in Google books provides some examples:

> From his window if he slid far enough down the pillow Jackson could see the flag on the church tower and know the strength and direction of the wind, and in March the first westerly of the year had the flag standing out straight.
>
> *Reservoir 13: A Novel* - Jon Mcgregor · 2017

> As Sidney Griffith explains, in Ephrem's “paradoxical view, the image of Nisibis, with her symbolic Persian flag standing out in the breeze, came to stand as a symbol for the defeat of the very paganism which, by the poet's own ...
>
> *Constantine and the Captive Christians of Persia: Martyrdom ...* - Kyle Smith · 2019

> There was a flagpole surrounded by chrysanthemums , the American flag standing out straight in the stiff wind .
>
> *Dream Country: A Novel* - Luanne Rice · 2008

> Meagan looked up at the Canadian maple leaf flag standing out in the ever-stiffening south wind, and then sighted down the road toward the bridge.
>
> *Red Sky in the Morning* - Bill Hamann · 2008

Answer (score 0):

UNFURLED
make or become spread out from a rolled or folded state, especially in order to be open to the wind.

Comment: You need to attribute your source.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U...you have posted a few interesting answers, but if you are quoting a source, you must cite the source to avoid legal complications...BTW, LQ answers like this are often deleted

Comment: A flag is unfurled in order to fly it.

Answer (score 0):

"Waving"

-Francis Scott Key (okay, not his exact phrasing)

[MW (verb definition 2)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wave) references waving as a feature of a flag.

Comment: "Does[...]yet wave" probably did not look like this after all that went on, those vocal leaps and the range.  Feel free to add another justification.

Answer (score -2):

The only term that comes to mind is "*Full Mast*" but that doesn't describe the **way** it's flowing in the wind - that describes the *height* at which it is in relation to the pole.

I suppose you could say the flag is flapping or swaying with the breeze?

Comment: 'Streaming out'?